# HOWTO catch timeout exception in Prolog

Tags: exception, timeout, prolog, swi-prolog

I want to limit "executing" of algorithm in prolog. Can you give me a hint, how to do it? I have found this predicate: [call_with_time_limit](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call_with_time_limit/2) How can I catch the time_limit_exceeded exception? Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I am trying it this way:

```
timeout(t) :-
    catch(call_with_time_limit(t, sleep(5)), X, error_process(X)).

error_process(time_limit_exceeded) :- write('Timeout exceeded'), nl, halt.
error_process(X) :- write('Unknown Error' : X), nl, halt.
```

but noting happend when I call timeout(1):

```
prolog :-
timeout(1),
```

but when I do it this way:

```
runStart :- call_with_time_limit(1, sleep(5)).

timeout(1) :-
    catch(runStart, X, error_process(X)).

error_process(time_limit_exceeded) :- write('Timeout exceeded'), nl, halt.
error_process(X) :- write('Unknown Error' : X), nl, halt.
```

and again call timeout(1) everything is fine.
Why? Thanks
**UPDATE 2:**

Problem solved, it is necessary to have predcate "argument" with upper case...

Comment: Variables start with an uppercase letter, i.e. t -> T.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900469/catch-3-and-call-with-time-limit-2-predicates-in-swi-prolog .

Comment: Could be duplicate but created 3 years before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`catch/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.9%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/exception.html%27%29%29). Example:

```
catch(call_with_time_limit(1,
                           sleep(5)),
      time_limit_exceeded,
      writeln('overslept!')).
```

More practically:

```
catch(call_with_time_limit(T, heavy_computation(X)),
      time_limit_exceeded,
      X = no_answer).  % or just fail
```

Comment: I have found nice tutorial: https://wiki.colby.edu/display/~amvartan/Exception+and+Error+Handling+in+Prolog

Answer (score 2):

```
loop :- loop.

loop_for_n_sec(N, Catcher) :-
    catch(
        call_with_time_limit(N, loop),
        Catcher,
        true
    ).
```

Usage:

```
?- loop_for_n_sec(1, Catcher).
Catcher = time_limit_exceeded
```